# OpenJPA ManytoOne doesnt load eagerly. Works fine in Websphere Community but not in JBoss

Tags: jpa, jboss, migration, websphere, openjpa

Same OpenJPA version 2.1.1 on both servers. Same Code persistence.xml . Same Mysql database. Same java annotations, but for ManytoOne annotations do not load eagerly on Jboss server whereas it works fine on Websphere Community edition.

Have a "return query.getResultList()" statement with a List as return type for the method.

EntityA has below ManytoOne.Added fetchtype of Eager eventhough default is Eager for this ManytoOne. Also tried to see if LoadFetchGroup needs to be added. Still did not work.

Also tried @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn instead of @JoinColumn. Didnt work.
`@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "report_status_id", referencedColumnName = "report_status_id")`

Basically, the queries to load the manytoone associations are not getting generated.

```
 @ManyToOne(optional = false,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
   // @LoadFetchGroup("detail")
    @JoinColumn(name = "report_type_id", referencedColumnName = "report_type_id")
    private ReportType reportType;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    //@ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "report_status_id", referencedColumnName = "report_status_id")
    private ReportStatus reportStatus;
-----------
Entity on the other side ReportType has this. Tried with both List return type and Set return type. 
  // @OneToMany(mappedBy = "reportType",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "reportType")
private Set<ReportFile> reportFileCollection;
```

Only way i was able to get it to work was by looping the return List and for each item accessing/printing contents of any of the EntityB/C values. Which means those manytoone entities are being loaded Lazily. This is a Migration project and so do not want to change too much of client code.

Haven even tried below in persistence.xml but no help.

```
<property name="openjpa.jdbc.EagerFetchMode" value="parallel"/>
<property name="openjpa.jdbc.SubclassFetchMode" value="join"/>
```

Bear in mind that code works with no issues on Websphere Community Edition server as is but only doesnt work in Jboss.

Comment: Check the [JBoss Windup migration tool](https://github.com/windup/windup/wiki).